# Simple Flask app - can't connect to database on localhost?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite, flask

I am trying to follow this tutorial:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-web-app-from-scratch-using-python-flask-and-mysql--cms-22972

I have the web app appearing, i can browse between pages and when I click "Sign up" after filling in details I get this error in python:

```
ERROR:__main__:Exception on /signUp [POST]
OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)")
```

I'm not sure whats happening here, i have a database called "BucketList.db" in the app.py root folder.

Is there a way to find out where is is getting stuck? or why it cannot connect to the db? I can connect directly to the database using Sqlite and it all seems fine so maybe something not right with how its accessed through localhost?

Any help/guidance would be appreciated! Thanks!!

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, json, request
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
from werkzeug import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

mysql = MySQL()
app = Flask(__name__)

# MySQL configurations
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'BucketList'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PORT'] = '5002'
mysql.init_app(app)

@app.route('/')
def main():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/showSignUp')
def showSignUp():
    return render_template('signup.html')


@app.route('/signUp',methods=['POST','GET'])
def signUp():
    try:
        _name = request.form['inputName']
        _email = request.form['inputEmail']
        _password = request.form['inputPassword']

        # validate the received values
        if _name and _email and _password:

            # All Good, let's call MySQL
            conn = mysql.connect()
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            _hashed_password = generate_password_hash(_password)
            cursor.callproc('sp_createUser',(_name,_email,_hashed_password))
            data = cursor.fetchall()

            if len(data) is 0:
                conn.commit()
                return json.dumps({'message':'User created successfully !'})
            else:
                return json.dumps({'error':str(data[0])})
        else:
            return json.dumps({'html':'<span>Enter the required fields</span>'})

    except Exception as e:
        return json.dumps({'error':str(e)})
    finally:
        cursor.close() 
        conn.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5002)
```

Comment: It looks like the code you're using connects to a MySQL database, but since you have a database called BucketList.db it looks like you're using SQLite , in short, you're trying to use the mysql driver to connect to sqlite which I'm not sure is possible, check here on using sqlite with flask http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/sqlite3/

Comment: Thanks, scrineym. I am far more used to sqlite in python and have a working version written and posted below. Now all thats left is the json parts arent working! At least I have the main bit I was stuck on fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code I got to work using the Sqlite implementation suggested by scrineym. It works to the point where you have an app that enters and commits to the database.

Now my only issue is the json parts arent working when I submit/get an error/no field data is written! At least theres one solution that works to the original question!

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, json, request
from werkzeug import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
import sqlite3
from flask import g 

DATABASE = 'BucketList.db'

#mysql = MySQL()
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def main():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/showSignUp')
def showSignUp():
    return render_template('signup.html')


@app.route('/signUp',methods=['POST','GET'])
def signUp():
    _name = request.form['inputName']
    _email = request.form['inputEmail']
    _password = request.form['inputPassword']

    # validate the received values
    if _name and _email and _password:
        print _name, _email

        db = g._database = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE)
        cursor = get_db().cursor()
        print "Database opened"

        _hashed_password = generate_password_hash(_password)
        print _hashed_password

        _userid = str(_name) + str(_hashed_password[0:4])
        db.execute('INSERT INTO tbl_user VALUES (?,?,?,?)',(_userid,_name,_email,_hashed_password))
        db.commit()

        data = cursor.fetchall()
        if len(data) is 0:
            conn.commit()
            return json.dumps({'message':'User created successfully !'})
        else:
            return json.dumps({'error':str(data[0])})
    else:
        return json.dumps({'html':'<span>Enter the required fields</span>'})

        cursor.close() 
        db.close()

        print "Database closed"

    "Print here"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5002)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try to avoid connecting again in finally clause. Simply, write conn.close() and cursor.close(). It should resolve your problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I forgot to take those out as i wanted to see if it would connect outside the "if" clause. (edited post to reflect this) Unfortunately I still have the same problem, it wont connect in the first place to let me close it.

Comment: It should work. Now, you should check whether **mysqld**(or mysql server instance) instance is running or not. Besides this, you also need to check the **PRIVILEGES** to the DB you are trying to connect. Most likely, it's the issue of mysql server which is either not running or you are providing unauthorized credentials while connecting to DB. Also, check the connection from command prompt. by typing command `mysql` on shell.